# Shared library compatibility issue

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, ocr, compatibility

Trying to use the nsocr (an OCR based application) shared library namely libjnsocr.so  & it works successfully on a Ubuntu system. When running the same on a RHEL 5.1 box, I get an error as 
`ERROR_DLLNOTLOADED      0x70010002  or Cannot find or load the "NSOCR.dll" file.`
One of the issues that might be the source is that Ubuntu runs on a recent version of Linux kernel i.e. 4.2 whereas the server where I am running the program is on kernel version 2.6 which is very old. 
Please let me know if there is some way to make this file compatible for the older kernel. Appreciate any other inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

> When running the same on a RHEL 5.1 box, I get an error as

... Would probably work if you used like Ubuntu 7.04 to create the 
libraries / the application.

Say libjnsocr.so depends on e.g. libc6 version 2.11 or later. Redhat 5 has glibc-2.5 ( = libc6-2.5 ) : No chance that any contemporary application can work.

---

Comment: I think you have a point there & essentially what you're saying therefore is to update the current glibc packages to version 2.11 or higher. Will check on that and see if that solves it. Thanks!

Comment: ´glibc' *is* your OS (together with the kernel) and can usually not be updated. However, you can build an extra glibc to a hidden location, like /opt/glibc211/ .... and point to the new glibc, when you are starting NSOCR. One possible pitfall : Your OS / the default kernel(-headers) may be too old to build glibc-2.11 .....

Comment: Thanks for the additional guidance. The RHEL 5.1 box is not something I can directly manage anyway and the IT team at my company said it would take additional clearances before they can give me an upgraded kernel or a RHEL 6.5 box that runs glibc 2.12. I ended up testing my code on a personal computer which had the required glibc version. There's still time to move this code into production so until then I can take a break:)